# Как определить значение в контроллере

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

У меня есть value - "LoginAction" как можно определить его в контроллере.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Custom login</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                color: #ff0000;
                font-weight: bold;
            }           
            .msg {
                color: #008000;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
    <h1>Login Form</h1>

    <c:if test="${not empty errorMessge}"><div style="color:red; font-weight: bold; margin: 30px 0px;">${errorMessge}</div></c:if>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name="loginForm" action='<spring:url value="/loginAction"/>' method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit">Login</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

AuthorizationController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AuthorizationController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
        m.addObject("title", "Successfully logged in");
        m.addObject("message", "home");
        m.setViewName("admin");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect: allStudents");
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }
}
```

Student Controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");

        return mv;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping("/loginAction")
public String loginAction(Model model,
                          @ModelAttribute("userName") String userName,
                          @ModelAttribute("password") String password,
                          HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("userName = " + userName);
        System.out.println("password = " + password);
        return "login_success"; //login_success.jsp для примера, нужно указать куда перенаправить.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо его в какой контроллер кинуть в авторизайшин или студент

Comment: я так понимаю authorization

Comment: вы там забыли return добавить, что возле return написать

Comment: куда перенаправить после успешного выполнения

Comment: Извините я вот перенаправил его в Allstudents.jsp но у меня там список студентов должен быть но список исчез

Comment: можно открыть с вам чат хочу с вам посоветоваться

Comment: да, можете начинать

Comment: блин у меня не получается открыть чат

Comment: В общем когда вы далете return "AllStudents" сервер отдаёт AllStudents.jsp, а у вас видимо просто контроллер, который на http отдаёт текст, не путайтесь.

Comment: как можно исправить

Comment: а можно спросить я только учусь, для чего нужен LoginAction

Comment: мне кажется вы слишком много пытаетесь понять за один раз, возможно сперва вам стоит отложить вопросы авторизации и поработать с JSP страницами, потом почитать что такое REST, разобраться в видах запросов (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH), создать несколько разных контроллеров (@Controller и @RestController) понять различия в них. Затем почитать что такое формы в html и только затем браться за авторизацию, в ваших комментариях слишком много вопросов, не уверен, что от моих ответов вам станет понятнее.

Comment: Можно последний вопрос  для чего нужен LoginAction

Comment: я не понимаю этот вопрос, что вы подразумеваете под LoginAction? Форму, ссылку, контроллер?

Comment: <form name="loginForm" action='<spring:url value="/loginAction"/>'

Comment: ну это html форма, она объединяет данные и по кнопке submit посылает эти данные на эндпоинт /loginAction

Comment: Спасибо))))))))